# Redirect correctly to a JSP inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am a but stuck and confused over this. I have all my .JSP files inside WEB-INF/pages/ and want to access them.

I have done a requestDispatcher on /forward/* like this

```
    @WebServlet("/forward/*")
public class ForwardController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + req.getPathInfo()).forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

This works great and I can access my JSP files using /forward/pages/index.jsp, though, what I have read so should this not be accessable for the user, but now it clearly is. Is this done in the right way?

Also, now that we've redirect to that link, http://localhost/forward/pages/index.jsp 
and want to logout, i use a button to /logout, but now the link before follows along like this, http://localhost/forward/pages/logout

How can I overcome these 2 things?

Best regards

Comment: Files in WEB-INF are not publicly accessible, but they can be accessible internally which is what `req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + req.getPathInfo()).forward(req, resp);` does. In short it doesn't send user request to access new resource under `/WEB-INF/...` but it internally decides that response for *current* request should be handled by internal (non-publicly accessible) JSP script. From what I remember it is good practice to have your JSP files representing view layer to be placed in WEB-INF to ensure that they will be only accessible via controller.

Comment: Yes you are right, but now that this have been applied, when I use forms for example, it will do an automatically link usage of the before forward, like forward/pages/index.jsp, and when I use <form action="login" it will go to the link forward/pages/login - How can I overcome this now?

Answer (score 0):

As said the jsp pages inside WEB-INF can only be accessible through controller so whenever you need to access any jsp from another jsp then you need to route through controller. If you want to access jsp to jsp then those should be outside WEB-INF

Comment: Okay I see, but why is it that we want to hide files inside WEB-INF? What kind of information is there that can be vulnerble, for users to know? And if we use the forward, that url can either way be accessed if the user knows it? Should it also be hidden with a url rewrite?

Comment: Normally the dynamic pages are placed inside WEB-INF and any static pages can be placed outside WEB-INF. User can always directly access pages which are outside WEB-INF